# Компиляция программ из Assembler (NASM unix 64bit intel)

Tags: c, ассемблер, unix, nasm

Есть программа:

```
   section .data
    msg db "Hello world!",10

section .text
    global start

start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 13
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

создаю объект:

```
nasm -f macho64 hello.asm
```

пытаюсь создать исполняемый файл:

```
ld hello.o -o hello
```

код ошибки:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

меняю start на _main, предупреждение:

```
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
```

исполняю:

```
[2]    8119 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

пишу main на с:

```
void    hello_asm(void);

int     main(void)
{
    hello_asm();
    return (0);
}
```

меняю _main на _hello_asm, компилирую, предупреждение:

```
    ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in
 code signed PIE, but used in _hello_asm from hello.o. To fix this warning, don't compile 
with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

исполняю:

```
[2]    8082 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

как в итоге нужно правильно все это делать?

Comment: из гугла по запросу «nasm macos» https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/7125822, http://salahuddin66.blogspot.com/2009/08/nasm-in-mac-os-x.html

Comment: > ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o 1 hello.o
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in start from hello.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie

Comment: дык, а вторая ссылка про то что указать точку входа?